# Update state with API-call through custom hook after another API-call React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Tried several solutions for this, but still struggling.

I have a functional component called `CVEdit` where data is displayed when fetched through custom hook `useFetchModularRules`. `CVEdit` also has a component called `BottomBar` with a button that trigger a PUT-call to the backend through `sendEditData` with data that has been cached through a custom Redux hook `useEditInput`.

I want to update the data in `CVEdit` when the PUT-call is made.

---

```
// CVEdit
const CVEdit = (): JSX.Element => {
    const { isLoading, error, data } = useFetchModularRules()

    return (
        <EditInputProvider>
            <>
                {error !== null ? (
                    <ErrorMessage error={error} />
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {isLoading ? (
                            <LoadingPage />
                        ) : (
                            <Box>
                                <CVContent data={data} />
                                <BottomBar />
                            </Box>
                        )}
                    </>
                )}
            </>
        </EditInputProvider>
    )
}
```

---

---

```
// BottomBar
const BottomBar = (): JSX.Element => {
    const { dispatch, editCache } = useEditInput()

    return (
        <Box>
            <SaveButton
                onClick={() => sendEditData(dispatch, editCache)}
            />
        </Box>
    )
}
```

---

---

```
// useFetchModularRules
type ReturnType = {
    data: null | IModularAnalysis
    isLoading: boolean
    error: AxiosError | null
}

export const useFetchModularRules = (): ReturnType => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<null | IModularAnalysis>(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState<AxiosError | null>(null)
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        const email = user?.username ?? ''

        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true)
            const headers = await getAuthHeader()
            const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
            await axios
                .get(`${baseUrl}/v2/analysis/${email}`, headers)
                .then((value) => {
                    setData(value.data)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setError(error)
                })
            setIsLoading(false)
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return {
        data,
        isLoading,
        error,
    }
}
```

---

---

```
// EditInputProvider
type Action = {
    type: 'cacheChanges' | 'saveChanges' | 'updateIds'
    value: Data | null | { uid: string; cvid: string }
}

export type Dispatch = (action: Action) => void

type Field = { name: string; value: string }
export type Path = { name: string; id: string; version: number }
export type Data = { headElement: string; path: Path[]; field: Field }
export type EditCache = { uid: string; cvid: string; data: Data[] }

type EditInputProviderProps = { children: ReactNode }

const EditStateContext = createContext<
    { editCache: EditCache; dispatch: Dispatch } | undefined
>(undefined)

const editReducer = (editCache: EditCache, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'updateIds': {
            const temp = action.value as {
                uid: string
                cvid: string
            }
            editCache.cvid = temp.cvid
            editCache.uid = temp.uid
            return editCache
        }
        case 'cacheChanges': {
            const newValue = action.value as Data
            const index = editCache.data.findIndex(
                (it) =>
                    it.path === newValue.path &&
                    it.field.name === newValue.field.name,
            )

            if (index === -1) {
                editCache.data.push(newValue)
            } else {
                editCache.data[index] = newValue
            }

            return editCache
        }
        case 'saveChanges': {
            const temp = editCache

            editCache.data = [] // Empty cache
            return temp
        }
        default: {
            throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`)
        }
    }
}

const EditInputProvider = ({
    children,
}: EditInputProviderProps): JSX.Element => {
    const [editCache, dispatch] = useReducer(editReducer, {
        uid: '',
        cvid: '',
        data: [],
    })
    const value = { editCache, dispatch }

    return (
        <EditStateContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </EditStateContext.Provider>
    )
}

const useEditInput = (): { editCache: EditCache; dispatch: Dispatch } => {
    const context = useContext(EditStateContext)
    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error('useEditInput must be used within a EditInputProvider')
    }

    return context
}

export { EditInputProvider, useEditInput }
```

---

---

```
// sendEditData
export const sendEditData = async (
    dispatch: Dispatch,
    editCache: EditCache,
): Promise<void> => {
    const headers = await getAuthHeaderPut()
    await axios
        .put(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/v2/edit/${editCache.uid}/${editCache.cvid}`,
            JSON.stringify(editCache.data),
            headers,
        )
        .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'saveChanges', value: null })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
        })
}
```

---

Comment: If I understand correctly then add whatever triggers the effect in `useFetchModularRules` to the effect dependencies. Currently you have missing dependencies as is because it depends on `user.username` at the moment.